# How to create Zip file and add files to specific folder all in memory using C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, stream, zip

I tried the following (just a quick PoC) approach but I'm getting an exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 
>   Message=Entries in create mode may only be written to once, and only one entry may be held open at a time.

```
    using (MemoryStream zipMS = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipMS, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
    //read the file bytes
    //byte[] fileToZipBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToZip);

    //create the entry - this is the zipped filename
    // just end with "/"
    ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry1 = zipArchive.CreateEntry("folder1/folderchild1/test/test.png");
    ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry2 = zipArchive.CreateEntry("folder1/folderchild1/test2/test2.png");

    //add the file 1 contents
    using (Stream zipEntryStream = zipFileEntry1.Open())
    using (BinaryWriter zipFileBinary = new BinaryWriter(zipEntryStream))
    {
        zipFileBinary.Write(ssnewImage1);
    }

    //add the file 2 contents
    using (Stream zipEntryStream2 = zipFileEntry2.Open())
    using (BinaryWriter zipFileBinary2 = new BinaryWriter(zipEntryStream2))
    {
        zipFileBinary2.Write(ssnewImage2);
    }

}

        using (FileStream finalZipFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\peters\Desktop\res.zip", FileMode.Create))
        {
            zipMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            zipMS.CopyTo(finalZipFileStream);
        }

    }
```

Hope someone can help me with this task.
Cheers

Comment: How about using a FileStreamer to create a file from the byte array and then use the C# ZipFile class to zip it/etc..?

Comment: Hi. I'm new in C# and I would really appreciate some code snippets with the best approaches in terms of performance since my use case really demands that.

Comment: Google FileStream.

Comment: I already tried something as I added to my initial question but I'm getting an exception.

Comment: Just fixed the issue.it was the fact I was creating an opening both entries!